# Error use other library when I use Rstudio and Roxygen2 to build a package

Tags: r

To simplify the problem. I tried the following thing. My goal is to build a simple package which need another library.

I used RStudio and tried to create a new package, and checked the project option to "Generate document with Roxygen". And I get the following code:

```
#' Title just a test
#'
#' @return nothing
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' hello()
hello <- function() {
  print("Hello, world!")
}
```

and I "check"ed it and "build and reload"ed it by the RStudio, all is OK.
Then I tried to add one line in the head of the code:

```
library("data.table")

#' Title just a test
#'
#' @return nothing
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' hello()
hello <- function() {
  print("Hello, world!")
}
```

Then I failed amd get the following:

```
* checking whether package 'kanpu.temp' can be installed ... ERROR
Installation failed."
```

When I check the log, it says that:

```
* installing *source* package 'kanpu.temp' ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in library("data.table") : there is no package called 'data.table'
Error : unable to load R code in package 'kanpu.temp'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'kanpu.temp'
* removing 'D:/onedrive/program/R/kanpu.temp.Rcheck/kanpu.temp'
```

I am sure that data.table is a existed package in my RStudio System. and also tried other package like "ggplot2", "plyr", and get the same result.

So how can I resolve this problem?

The envirement is:

```
Win7 64
RStudio 0.99.473
R 3.1.3 64
```

---

After checking the "Writing R Extensions", I know what's wrong with the code.

I should use "Import" or "Depends" in the "DESCRIPTION" file.

Comment: why would you need to have that library call there?

Comment: To simplify the question, I removed all other code.The real code need ggplot2.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the error message, it seems that you do not have the `ggplot2` package installed. This will cause an error when R reaches the line `library(ggplot2)`.

The solution is to install that package:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

*However*, you probably shouldn't be calling `library` in your packaged code. A package should make as few changes to the external environment as possible.

Instead, mark the package as required in your `DESCRIPTION` and make fully qualified function calls: `SomePackage::someFunction()`.

See [Hadley's pages for further information](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/).

Comment: I am sure that ggplot2 has been installed, and I also tried other package such as "data.table", "plyr" and get the same result. Your suggestion is good, but it doesn't solve my question. Thank you.

Comment: What is the `library` call for? If you need to access a package's members, use `::`. If you want to ensure that when your package is loaded another also gets loaded, put that package in the `Depends` section of your `DESCRIPTION`. Another idea: have you tried calling `library("data.table") in the console *before* you build in RStudio?